# Max partition by DAX measure equivalent?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

In DAX/Power BI, I wondering if it is possible to create an aggregate calculation on a subset of data within a dataset.

I have a listing of customer scores for a period of time, e.g.

```
date,   customer, score
-----------------------
1.1.17, A,        12
2.1.17, A,        16
4.1.17, B,        10
5.1.17, B,        14
```

I would like to identify to Max date per customer eg.

```
date,   customer, score, max date per client
-------------------------------------------
1.1.17, A,        12,    2.1.17
2.1.17, A,        11,    2.1.17
4.1.17, B,        10,    5.1.17
5.1.17, B,        14,    5.1.17
```

The SQL equivalent would something like-

```
MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer).
```

In DAX/Power BI I  realise that a calculated column can be used in combination with EARLIER but this will not be suitable because the calculated column is not responsive to filtering from a slicer. I.e I would like to find the MAX date per client as illustrated above for a filtered date range controlled from a slicer and not for the full data set which is what a calculated column does.  Is such a measure possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will want a measure like this:

```
Max Date by Customer = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Table1[Date]),
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(Table1),
            Table1[customer] = MAX(Table1[customer])
         )
     )
```

The `ALLSELECTED` removes the local filter context while preserving any slicer filtering.

The filter `Table1[customer] = MAX(Table1[customer])` is basically the measure equivalent of `Table1[customer] = EARLIER(Table1[customer])` in a calculated column.

Comment: Alexis- Thank YOu - this is what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select *, (select max(t1.date) 
           from table t1 
           where t1.customer = t.customer
          ) as max_date_per_client
from table t;
```

Comment: Thank you however I am specifically hoping to get some more specific DAX advice

Comment: sorry please would you explain how can you have a SQL query in DAX?